# Unity crashes when using scale effect(spreading windows/super+w) 14.04

Tags: unity, compiz, 14.04, crash, unity-tweak-tool

I don't know what happened but I changed some stuff in Unity Tweak Tool and now whenever I use Super + W combination to use scale effect(I think this is what it is called, it spreads all open windows), Unity crashes and I have to restart `lightdm` to get it back. I only changed theme to radiance, set up some hot corners and disabled/enabled Window spread(also checked and unchecked "Icons on previews" and "Click to access desktop" boxes). I've tried to undo every possible change I made but no use whenever I press Super + W, Unity crashed(no launcher, no top bar, no window decorations). How can I safely fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm this happens on my desktop too. The only solution I've found so far is to delete all your user configuration files (.compiz/, .gconf/ and maybe some .config/ subdirs) which is very annoying because you loose all of your settings and have to start over. It may affect other applications' configuration too...

I stopped using unity tweak tool because it leads to Unity randomly crashing all the time. And it's a shame, because Unity offers very little customization by itself.

There are some bug reports here related with this problem but nobody seems to be doing anything about it:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/compiz/+bug/1255711

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1293242

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1284898

Comment: After messing with CompizConfig Settings Manager, I've ended up with some serious problems and then I had to use `unity-reset`. Now it's been solved but it is sad that there is no proper solution yet. Thanks for your reply though!

Comment: yw. I think it's better not to use those tools like ccsm or unity tweak... they've ruined my desktop plenty of times!